# Can't change raspbian folder permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a **USB drive mounted to a folder** in my raspberry pi. I'm using that drive to host an FTP server with Gadmin-ProFTPD. However, I cannot upload or download anything no matter what permissions I give a user. It looks like this:

```
ftp> put test.txt
local: test.txt remote: test.txt
200 PORT command successful
550 test.txt: Permission denied
ftp>
```

**I think this has to do with folder permissions** because the folders in the flash drive have the Access control `Change Content` permission set to `Only owner`. However, when I change it to say `Anyone` and press OK, next time I open the properties it is back to `Only Owner`. This happens regardless of how I answer the `Do you want to recursively apply these changes to all files and sub-folders?` (which I do). **Why can I not change permissions this way and how can I get past this?**

Answer (score 2):

File permissions can only be changed on filesystems which support file permissions. This *does not* include FAT/FAT32 or exFAT. (It may include NTFS if permission mapping was enabled at mount time, but it isn't by default.)

For filesystems which have no Unix permissions support, you need to specify a global value at mount time. The option name might vary, for FAT it's `fmask` and `dmask`. For example:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt -t vfat -o uid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=022
```

Comment: Ah yes, I'm confusing them with fmode/dmode.

Comment: @grawiy when I did this command it appeared to work and the files that are on the drive appeared in the folder I wanted it to mount in, except it is saying it is not mounted, and the files are listed as being stored on the hard drive (or SD card rather)

Comment: This isn't working. What do I have wrong here? Any chance I can make it mount on startup instead of manually? `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/pi/FTP-SERVER -o uid=1FCE-8722,fmask=0133,dmask=022,umask=000`

Comment: This is what fdisk -l gives me: 
 ```Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 61071359 61069312 29.1G 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to be ext4 and made proftpd the owner with `chown proftpd /home/pi/FTP-SERVER`. I'm making it automount with /ext/fstab.